# import statement in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why give full path to call a function when import statement is used to import a module from subpackage of package?

eg . A is package , AA is sub package of A , AA1 is module in AA

```
import A.AA.AA1

A.AA.AA1.AA1fun()
```

works correctly

but

```
AA1.AA1fun()
```

Why not this and why is 'A' got placed in global namespace why not 'AA1'?

Comment: import A.AA.AA1 as AA1

Comment: i know about aliasing and from statement but i want to know about the reason behind giving full path in sole import statement?

Comment: for disambiguation I guess

Answer (score 3):

Let's suppose that we perform an `import` of these two modules:

```py
import A.AA.AA1
import B.AA.AA1
```

Which of the two modules would be chosen if you run the following functions?

```py
AA.AA1.fun()
AA.AA1.fun()
AA1.fun()
AA1.fun()
```

To avoid this ambiguity you have to explicitly put the whole package, subpackage and module path.

```py
A.AA.AA1.fun()
B.AA.AA1.fun()
```

If you want to avoid having to use the whole path every time, you have the `from` option:

```py
from A.AA.AA1 import fun
fun()
```

But, by doing this, the name of the identifier `fun` is exposed. Therefore, if `fun` was already assigned to another object previously, it is overridden and now points to the new object in *A.AA.AA1*.

```py
fun = lambda x: 2*x
from A.AA.AA1 import fun
from B.AA.AA1 import fun
```

In this last example, after executing these lines of code, `fun` refers only to the object in *module B.AA.AA1*.

You can also use the `as` option to create an alias to the imported module:

```py
import A.AA.AA1 as AAA1
import B.AA.AA1 as BAA1

AAA1.fun()
BAA1.fun()
```

This way the whole path is abbreviated and avoids ambiguity when executing `fun` from one module or another.

In this link you can find the documentation: [import doc](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html)

Comment: Please explain about namespace too . I.e why  ' A '  is added to the global namespace instead of ' AA1 '. Bcz only AA1 is imported in program

Comment: @harshit Perfect. I'll leave it pending for when I have some time. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is in how `import` works, please refer to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) section 5.4.2 for more information. As an example:

```
import A.AA.AA1

A.AA.AA1.AA1fun()
```

With as sole import you will have to provide the complete path. On the other hand, if you use a `from` statement you can use it directly:

```
from A.AA import AA1

AA1.AA1fun()
```